# My access to word merge code is not working

Tags: vba, ms-access, merge, ms-word

I have made a form in access and I'm trying to code a "merge to word" button but my code has a problem and I dont know how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Command102_Click()
Dim LWordDoc As String
Dim oApp As Object

'Path to the word document
LWordDoc = "C:\school\information tech\document.docx"

If Dir(LWordDoc) = "" Then
  MsgBox "Document not found."

Else
  'Create an instance of MS Word
  Set oApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
  oApp.Visible = True

  'Open the Document
  oApp.Documents.Open FileName:=Document.docx
End If
End Sub
```

If someone could help that would be great. Ill attach screenshots of the error I get when I click the button and the code as the debugger is pointing to the problem. (pointing to the start of the "oApp.Documents.Open FileName:=Document.docx" line)

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Since you create a variable to hold the filename, try using that:

```
oApp.Documents.Open FileName:=LWordDoc
```